# Ruby trying to push to hash with (**parameter)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to multiple[sic] parameters to a hash and getting this error:

> `method': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Could someone tell me how I could accomplish this/what I am doing wrong?

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :variable
  def initialize
    @variable = {}
  end
  def method(**parameter)
    parameter.each {|k,v| @variable[k] = v}
  end
end

new_class = MyClass.new
p new_class.method(["key", 1],["house", 2],["key", 3])
```

Comment: try `new_class.method(key:1,house:2)` if you are using newest version of ruby.

Comment: All you need do is remove one `*`.

Comment: Alternatively, remove `**` and invoke with a single argument:  `new_class.method([["key", 1],["house", 2],["key", 3]])`.

Comment: Double splat syntax only works when all the relevant keys are symbol. In your case there is no hope using `**`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider more idiomatic use of Ruby

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @variable = {}
  end

  def method hash
    @variable.merge! hash
  end
end
```

Then use it like this

```
foo = MyClass.new
foo.method a: 1, b: 2
```

The last line is sugared-up Ruby for

```
foo.method({:a => 1, :b => 2})
```

[Hash#merge! docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21)

Comment: You may wish to explain the last line of code, as Rob is quite new to Ruby.